# Get driver file version in windows

Tags: c#, system, drivers

How can I get file attributes or version info of driver file in windows via c#.
I'm using this code:

```
var version = File.GetAttributes(Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\drivers\acpi.sys");
```

but this code throw exception: `Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\acpi.sys'.`.
Then i'm using this code `var dir = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\drivers");` in dir variable i have 4 files. If I open this folder via windows explorer i have in folder 300+ files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not on Windows 95 anymore, there's a lot more things between your application and the system. Why are you even trying to read the version of `acpi.sys`?

Comment: @Luaan this is the example. I need to read information of another file. This problem is not for only acpi.sys.

Comment: You're talking about drivers. Why are you querying driver versions? And why are you trying to do that by reading the file version in the file system?

Comment: In my company some drivers very often changes version. And I need to show information of driver.

Answer (score 2):

You should using >= **FrameWork .net 4,** 
add :

```
using System.Management;
```

and add the reference **System.Management**;

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                        "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var manObj in moc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device Name:" + manObj["FriendlyName"] + " \r\nDeviceID: " + manObj["DeviceID"] + "\r\nDriverDate: " + manObj["DriverDate"] + "\r\nDriverVersion: " + manObj["DriverVersion"] + "\r\nDriverName:" + manObj["DriverName"] +"\n\r======================================\n\n";);  
        }
```

Result (part):

[image]

Comment: How can i query driver by name of sys file?

Comment: @EXTRAM Don't. You're still looking at this from the entirely wrong perspective. The physical `sys` files are just a detail that has no importance. Instead, go by the device IDs, like the `ClassGuid` or USB vendor/device pairs.

Comment: `ManagementObjectSearcher` is a slow pain in the butt, rather use the file version if its correct.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be reading the version from the file directly. Should work for 64/32bit apps, but I am not sure if you can get to all files.

```
string directory;

if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    directory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "Sysnative");
else
    directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);

var info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(directory, "drivers", "acpi.sys"));
```

You can find more information about Sysnative folders at [Folders under C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers created with Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082629/folders-under-c-windows-system32-grouppolicyusers-created-with-directory-create) or [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector)