# Folders under C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers created with Directory.Create not showing up

Tags: c#, security

I'm creating a utility in C# that will allow the manufacturing department at my company to easily Apply or Remove a predefined non-administrative Group Policy on a fresh machine. Without going into too much precise detail on this matter, the group policy restricts desktop functionality for non-administrative users on a given machine.

I have proven that if I manually copy files from one Windows 7 machine to another in the C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers folder using the Windows Explorer and then call gpupdate /force from a command prompt, it works perfectly as I expect. Specifically, I'm copying the following folder into C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers: S-1-5-32-545. When I try to create this directory using the "CreateDirectory" method in .NET however, the folder doesn't show up when I try to view it using Windows Explorer. I know the folder is being created because after I create the directory, I verify its existence by calling "Directory.Exists"

Here is some sample code that should illustrate the issue I'm having. Please note: you need to run this sample code "As Administrator" in order to have the proper permissions:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var security = new System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity();

                security.AddAccessRule(
                new FileSystemAccessRule(
                    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null),
                    FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                    InheritanceFlags.None | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                    PropagationFlags.None,
                    AccessControlType.Allow));


                security.AddAccessRule(
                  new FileSystemAccessRule(
                      new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null),
                      FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                      InheritanceFlags.None | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                      PropagationFlags.None,
                      AccessControlType.Allow));


                security.AddAccessRule(
                       new FileSystemAccessRule(
                           new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null),
                           FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                           InheritanceFlags.None | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                           PropagationFlags.None,
                           AccessControlType.Allow));


                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers\S-1-5-32-545", security);

                if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers\S-1-5-32-545"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory exists.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory does NOT exist!");
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

After running this, use the Windows Explorer to navigate to this newly created folder and you will see that it's not visible, even though I have the Windows Explorer settings set to show hidden files. Any ideas?

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks, Scott!!!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Can you please write up your comment as an answer, and I will make it the Accepted Answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is 32 bit, the folder is going to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\GroupPolicyUsers` either make your app `AnyCPU` so it will run 64 bit on 64 bit systems and 32 bit on 32 bit systems or leave it 32 bit and use the following code.

```
string directory;

if(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    directory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),"Sysnative");
}
else
{
    directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
}
```

the `sysnative` folder is a meta-folder that only exists to 32 bit apps on a 64 bit system, it redirects to the real 64 bit system32 folder.

See the MSDN page on the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information on how the redirection process works.

Comment: Scott Chamberlain, thank you for this answer! This really helped me a lot. I wish I would have posted this question sooner instead of struggling with this for hours!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment by user: Scott Chamberlain, I think I now understand what the issue is. My app must be a 32-bit app because indeed, the folder is getting created under C:\Windows\SysWOW64\GroupPolicyUsers.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I didn't notice the time stamps. Thanks.